# How do i print multiple lines from a json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an html code where we print multiple lines from a json file. However, the code does not seem to only if there is one line. How can I edit my code to allow multiple users to be printed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var jobj=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=""; //clear text
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+= "User Name"+":"+jobj['uname']+"<br>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+= "Status"+":"+jobj['status']+"<br>";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "my_data.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>My Contacts</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Contacts</button>
    <div id="demo"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the json file

```
{"uname":"Sam","status":"idle"}
{"uname":"Tom","status":"not idle"}
{"uname":"Bob","status":"idle"

}
```

Comment: Parse the json file to an array or object and loop over it, printing that line for each user.

Comment: the json seems to be incorrect. Please share the json

Comment: That JSON is invalid. Write real JSON first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it. Just iterate over each object in your array using `forEach` or a `for(...)` loop.

```js
let data = [{"uname":"Sam","status":"idle"},
{"uname":"Tom","status":"not idle"},
{"uname":"Bob","status":"idle"}],
demo = document.getElementById("demo")

data.forEach( obj => demo.innerHTML += `Name: ${obj.uname}, Status: ${obj.status}<br>`)
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

More info here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split this string into an array via:

```
var lines = this.responseText.split("\n")
```

Then loop over these and parse each.  The string as a whole that you read from that file is not valid json, but each individual line is.

Comment: So, instead of using `JSON.parse()`, you want to make chunks of `'{"uname":"Sam","status":"idle"}'` strings, then parse each of them? Parse how? How do you actually achieve OP's wanted result?

Comment: My apologies, I imagined it would be inferred that he should parse each line in the same way that he was previously trying to parse the entire file content.  JSON.parse() each line.